# FOREIGN KEY -ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm new using ORACLE SQL and I'm having a hard time trying to create a FOREIGN KEY.
What I made so far:

```
    CREATE TABLE PESSOA(
PES_CODE INT,
PES_NOME VARCHAR2(40),
CPF INT,
RG VARCHAR2(20),
EMAIL VARCHAR2(30) UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (PES_CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR(
TITULACAO VARCHAR2(20),
FOREIGN KEY (PES_CODE) REFERENCES PESSOA(PES_CODE);
);
```

Adding "FOREIGN KEY (PES_CODE) REFERENCES PESSOA(PES_CODE)" leds me to "ORA-00904: "PES_CODE": invalid identifier" error (Using LiveSQL). 
I also tried something like

```
CONSTRAINT FK_PES_COD
FOREIGN KEY (PES_CODE) REFERENCES PESSOA(PES_CODE)
```

But, again, it remains the same error and I don't understand why.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Declare the column before the `foreign key` constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the column and then create the foreign key constraint as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR(
TITULACAO VARCHAR2(20),
PES_CODE INT, -- this
CONSTRAINT PROFESSOR_PESCODE_FK FOREIGN KEY (PES_CODE) REFERENCES PESSOA(PES_CODE)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I Tried this way but now its shows "Missing Right Parenthesis"

Comment: Updated the answer, there was additional ; which is removed now!! test it now..